# Change JSON call with ng-click

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have the following problem and I just can't find a solution.

This is my current JS file for Angular:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("dota2impetus", [ ]);

    app.controller("heroGuide", ["$scope", "$http", function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.heroes = [ ];

        $http.get("js/custom/heroes.json").success(function(data) {
            $scope.heroes = data;
        });

    }]);

})();
```

JSON:

```
{
    "cw": [
        {
            "name": "Clockwerk",
            "abbr": "cw",
            "type": "r-str-big",
            "roles": "Initation, Durable"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have no problem getting the data from my JSON with the following calls:

```
{{ heroes.cw[0].name }}
{{ heroes.cw[0].type }}
{{ heroes.cw[0].roles }}
```

I need to use a variable though so I can replace cw with the abbreviation I get from ng-click.

```
<div title="Clockwerk" ng-click="selectHero(heroes.cw[0].abbr)"></div>
```

I am trying to accomplish this with the function from ng-click:

```
$scope.selectHero = function(selectedHero) {
    $scope.name = heroes.selectedHero[0].name;
};
```

It should now display Clockwerk in {{ name }} but it won't work. Is there anything I'm missing?

Basically I want to keep {{ heroes.x[0].name }} and the x should be replaced with the value I get from my function in ng-click (in this example it's "cw").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `[]` object notation which lets you pass a variable between the braces

```
$scope.name = heroes[selectedHero][0].name;
```

Comment: Well, I feel somewhat stupid now. Thanks, works perfect!